# 404 error when changing language

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, store-view, language

I added a new store for chinese language. I am using Magento 1.9 
When I change the store; My URL is :

http://www.********.com/app/etc/local.xml?___store=chinese&___from_store=default

I am new to Magento and no idea how to solve this problem.

Need help urgently.

Comment: store url should not contain `app/etc/local.xml` in it , you may have some typo in the code

Comment: i havnt added any code. 
--> i added the language package in app/local. 
--> then created a new store and changed the Locale in configuration to the Chinese ( the other language that i am trying to add. )

Answer (score 0):

To access to your store via the code, you have to do this: `www.domaine.com/?___store=chinese`, chinese should be your store code `<?php echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode(); ?>`

Comment: where should i add this ?

Comment: In the url, the address bar of your browser `www.domaine.com/?___store=chinese`

Comment: where should i add this-->  .com/?___store=chinese&___from_store=default
If i do this it works. 
where should i add <?php ...

Comment: No, you haven't to add the `<?php echo Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode(); ?>` it was just to check your store code if you want. you just need the first url

Comment: how should i solve the error ?

Comment: I don't know what is your need, can you give me the website url ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66530/discussion-between-deeksha-bajaj-and-prince).